# Using QGIS 3.0 raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, raster-calculator

[image]

I have a lesson/class assignment that teaches the use of format and export environmental raster data, but the issue is the lesson is outdated from the new QGIS version.

Lesson states:

Multiply the values in two layers together, or (as here)
divide all values in a layer by 10. In QGIS, go to Raster > Raster Calculator. Now, select the layer you want to manipulate (bio_1) by double-clicking it, select the name and directory of the Output layer, and then type the expression to divide by 10 – use the buttons, not your keyboard to type / 10:

Then click OK!

The QGIS 3.0 program doesn't allow you to create a new output file (or to my knowledge).

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those instructions seem perfectly valid for the Raster Calculator in QGIS 3.0.

Output file settings are in the upper-right corner of the Raster Calculator window. Enter the filepath and name for your new raster where it says "Output layer."

[image]

Comment: It won't let me type anything in, in order to click “ok” button on the raster calculator.

Comment: Are you running QGIS 3.0.2?

Comment: My QGIS info: QGIS version 3.0.0-Girona, Compiled against Qt 5.9.3, Compiled against GDAL/OGR 2.2.3, SpatiaLite Version 4.4.0-RC0, QWT Version 6.1.3, QScintilla2 Version 2.10.3

Comment: This might be related to this bug: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18417

Comment: You might want to install QGIS 2.18, which is the latest *stable* version of the program. QGIS 3.0 is in early release, and the developers are still working out the bugs.